# Ｗork in indirect-buffer faster than in original?

Tags: buffers, narrowing, indirect-buffers

When I read the org-manual which are about 12,000 lines long,
it's slow to edit such a large file.

Then I invoke "narrow-to-substree" and read "2.Documents Structure" in a indirect-buffer.

At this moment, I feel operations smoothly than before?

Is it a illusion or reality?

Comment: There are insufficient facts in your question for anyone to answer definitively.  What minor-modes and mode-line packages, if any, do you have enabled that could cause expensive editing?  Are you scrolling the window?  Type `C-h m` in both the direct and indirect buffer to perform a comparison and see which potential packages are expensive.  Also, profile the movements in each buffer ... `M-x profiler-start`, do stuff, `M-x profiler-report`, read the results, then back to the target buffer and `M-x profiler-stop`, then repeat the process in the other buffer ... identify what is expensive ...

Comment: What @lawlist said. Define your feeling that "operations" are more "smooth" than before. But yes, if you've narrowed the buffer (whether indirect or not) then there is less text that will be handled - searched, counted, etc.

Comment: This is yes/no question, so the answer is not terribly useful.  You might like to rephrase it so that an answer tells you more than just yes or no.

Comment: I am confirming that does indirect-buffer a   separated one or a part of the original @Stefan

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, but in any case you shouldn't "improve your question via comments": edit your question instead.